# How to disable ripple effect in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

How to disable ripple effect in Angular 7, for Angular Material `matSlideToggle` button?

I have already tried
`<mat-slide-toggle disableRipple></mat-slide-toggle>`
and
`<mat-slide-toggle [disableRipple]="true"></mat-slide-toggle>`.

It used to work in Angular 6 but, after upgrade to Angular 7 it stopped working.

Comment: Please create a Plunker or a StackBlitz project so that the community can help you faster and better.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade to 7.